# Search for total days and attendance at laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-blade, query-builder

I want to ask how to get the total days to 30 days. Then after getting a total value of 30 days, the total attendance is sought. The flow that I caught (total days - attendance).

My model:

```
public function total_hari($id)
{
    
    $from = date("Y-m-26", strtotime("-1 months"));
    $to = date('Y-m-d');

    $absen = DB::table('working_schedule')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->where('karyawan_id', '=', $id)
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->where('date', '<=', $to)
    ->where('date', '>=', $from)
    ->get();        
    return ($absen[0]->total);

}

public function alpha_bulan_ini($id)
{
    
    $from = date("Y-m-26", strtotime("-1 months"));
    $to = date('Y-m-d');
    $total_hari = $this->total_hari($id);
    $absen = DB::table('karyawan_absensi')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as alpha'))
    ->where('karyawan_id', '=', $id)
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->where('tanggal', '<=', $to)
    ->where('tanggal', '>=', $from)
    ->get(); 
    $total_hari = $total_hari ?? 0;
    $absen = isset($absen[0] ) ? $absen[0]->alpha : 0;
    //return ($total_hari-$absen);
    return ($total_hari);
}
```

My index.blade:

```
<td style='text-align:center'>{{ isset($key->absensihari) ? $key->total_hari($key->karyawan_id) : ''}}</td>
<td style='text-align:center'>{{ isset($key->absensihari) ? $key->alpha_bulan_ini($key->karyawan_id) : ''}}</td>
```

My table working_schedule:

| id | karyawan_id | date | working_id | type_id | mass_id | created_by | updated_by | deleted_by | created_at | updated_at | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1113 | 2019-10-01 | 1 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) |  |
| 2 | 42 | 2019-05-26 | 4 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | 1 | (NULL) | 2019-10-22 23:43:03 | 2019-10-22 23:43:03 |  |
| 3 | 42 | 2019-05-27 | 5 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | 1 | (NULL) | 2019-10-22 23:43:07 | 2019-10-22 23:43:07 |  |
| 4 | 42 | 2019-05-28 | 3 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | 1 | (NULL) | 2019-10-22 23:43:11 | 2019-10-22 23:43:11 |  |
| 5 | 42 | 2019-05-29 | 4 | (NULL) | (NULL) | (NULL) | 1 | (NULL) | 2019-10-22 23:43:14 | 2019-10-22 23:43:14 |  |

[image]

[Table working_schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w17he.png)

Comment: Hi Johan, would it be possible for you to copy/paste your code and put it in your question above?

Comment: Can add brief what exactly is the issue ?

Comment: For a total of days I want to find the results to be 30 days.  Then for the aplha_bulan_ini function it wants to find the result for attendance.  To get attendance results you have to find the total value of the day first.  And for the results of these two functions do not match what I was looking for.